# Sistema de Agendamento Windows ,SQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Como faço pra **criar** e rodar um comando sql(postgresql) no sistema de agendamentodo windows?

Meu problema.

tenho um banco de dados postgresql  onde tenho duas tabela.Uma é cliente e a outra é locação de disco.
Preciso saber se a locação desse disco ja passou da data de entrega.
Quero fazer de forma automática através da data.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um [recurso de agendamento](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) que roda dentro do PostgreSQL, permitindo rodar atualizações no banco, como neste exemplo:

```
-- Delete old data on Saturday at 3:30am (GMT)
SELECT cron.schedule('30 3 * * 6', $$DELETE FROM events WHERE event_time < now() - interval '1 week'$$);
```

Comment: É funcional no windows ?